# How to print out non-prime numbers? PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

This code is meant to print out non prime numbers between 1 and 30. How does it work and where is the error.

```
BEGIN  
    <<outer>>
    FOR i in 1..30
        <<inner>> 
        for k in 2..i-1 loop 
            if (mod(i, k) = 0) THEN 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
                exit inner when (mod(i, k)= 0);
            end if;
        end loop inner
    end loop outer 
end;
```

Comment: Well obviously it doesn't work.  `k in 2..i-1` resolves to `k in 2..0` when `i=1`.  There's other bugs as well but this smacks of Code Golf, so it's Off Topic.

Comment: @APC: that, surprisingly, does appear to work. The output is correct once you've fixed the syntax errors. the5strace: please correct the syntax (look closely at your two "for" lines, you'll see a difference). Then remember that the `;` aren't just decoration. There's places where they're required.

Comment: @APC the case `i=1` works because plsql requires the first bound to be lower than the second to enter the loop. reversing the iteration order requires the modifier `REVERSE` as in `FOR k IN REVERSE lo..hi LOOP ...END LOOP`.

Comment: @Mat - quite right, should have tested it before I posted.

Comment: The error is that it doesn't print 1, which (according to common understanding) is not a prime number and should therefore be printed.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - I'm going to quibble over your use of "common understanding." I would guess most people of a non-mathematical bent still think 1 is a prime. I agree that modern mathematics considers this not to be the case anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "how does it work" answer.

The outer loop handles going through numbers 1 - 30.

The inner loop does the actual Non-Prime number processing. It really gets going only after `i = 4` (since 1,2,3 are prime). For most non-prime numbers, the loop will finish after while `k <= 3` and it will print out `i`. 
For prime numbers it is going to loop through all the numbers less than the prime. Like if we are on `i = 23` the inner loop is going to go through 2,3,4...22 and complete the loop without printing anything.

That is the part that I don't like. If you factor out numbers (especially since we are only dealing with 1 - 30) they are divisible by 2 or 3 or another Prime number. Here is the silly part. Going back to our `i = 23` example. We are going to process both mod(23, 3) and mod(23, 9) and mod(23, 18). Well of course if 3 produces a remainder than 9 and 18 will produce a remainder as well (as will every subsequent number with a factor of 3).

Answer (score 5):

Had a coffee break, so here's a pure SQL implemementation.

```
with data as ( select level as n# from dual 
               connect by level <= 30 )
select distinct d1.n#
from data d1 cross join data d2
where d1.n# > d2.n#
and d2.n# != 1
and mod(d1.n#, d2.n#) = 0
order by d1.n#
```

Hypocrisy?  heck yeah!

---

This solution has the same inefficiency [which @TYH points out in the PL/SQL solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172354/146325).  That's why it needs the `distinct`.  Probably this could be optimised with a recursive CTE (only available in 11gR2  ).

Comment: Hypocrisy? Why do things in PL/SQL when you can do them in SQL?

Comment: @Colin'tHart - I agree.  But I called hypocrisy because I had already suggested this was Code Golf rather than a proper question.

Comment: A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds.  Hypocritize away, oh great thinker!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

the code works by testing all potential candidates, meaning all positive integers greater than 1 and less the number under scrutiny. if a candidate divides the tested number without remainder, the number is composite and will be printed. any further tests on hat number are skipped.